# Call one fragment from another

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, tabview

I'm very bad in explaining things, i'll try to do my best :)

I was trying to use a Tabhost and display list fragments in each tab.

[ListFragments in tabview]:[image]

This is how it looks.

On click on the list element, another fragment is invoked to display the details, it's displaying as below.
[Onclick on the list elements]:[image]

There are 2 problems.

1. The DetailsFragment is not full screen. i.e. an able to see the list(u can see in the above image)
2. When i go back to the tab view and click on the list it says :
   `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread`. `[in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)]`
   "
   TabView xml:

   ```
   <TabHost
       android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <TabWidget
               android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:orientation="horizontal" />

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="0" />

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1" />
       </LinearLayout>
   </TabHost>
   ```

detailsFragment xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Msg Id"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="PID"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Sender BS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Sender NS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Sender Interface"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Receiver BS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv6"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Receiver NS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Receiver Interface"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv8"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Msg Type"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv9"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Msg State"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Exe Time"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv11"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Init Time"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv12"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Send Time"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv13"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Admin User"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv14"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:text="Payload"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv15"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#a09f9f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code and logcat as well.

Comment: If the below is not helping provide a Code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.

Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)] "
```

Please call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `yourListView.requestLayout()` in the UI thread after adding items.The problem is that your collection that bound to Adapter is changed in the Background thread. Hence the solution is moving it to UI thread(as I stated above) or simply wrapping it with `runOnUiThread()`.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    your_collection.add(item);
    your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    yourListView.requestLayout();
  }
});
```

**To call another fragment the current:**

```
SecondFragment secFrag = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragment,secFrag );
                    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTransaction.commit();
```

**EDIT:**

**To Display Detail fragment full Screen, please make following changes:**

1. In your scrollView
   Replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
2. In your TableLayout
   Replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the first issue is solved :) but the second issue is that the new fragment is only half the screen i.e. its is shown above the list fragment. i want that fragment to take complete sceen

Comment: I m glad that your first issue is resolved. Plz provide the relevant xml files.

Comment: I have posted the xml files.

Comment: I have updated my answer, plz see my post. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: :( nope... its not solved... the exact problem i'm facing is... the details fragment is getting loaded in the same list fragment... :( i'm not sure if m explaing it properly

Answer (score 0):

For the above You need to simply add a fragment you just need an instance of:

For example-

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Search fragment = new  Search();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragment , "MY_FRAG");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have aleady done this. the problem i'm facing now is : on click on the listFragment,  it does not appear on the full scree, reather it appears only in some part of the screen. as i have shown in image 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Search fragment = new  Search();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragment , "MY_FRAG");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It really helped you to use fragment from another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

**Use hadler to notify your list because you can not access any UIComponents from background or worker thread, so it must be access from UI Thread. To ensure that use following trick.**

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```