# one Fragment activity to another fragment-activity how to call

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

for example one activity class to another activity class

using Intent methods

```
Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

my question was how to call fragment-activity to another fragment-activity..?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375149/call-one-fragment-form-another

Comment: There Fragment Activity Parent class is Activity so you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375149/call-one-fragment-form-another
Check this

Comment: Calling one FragmentActivity from another FragmentActivity is same as you call one Activity from another Activity

Comment: sorry my English very bad i know i create two fragment-activity bro

Comment: do you want to jump from FragmentActivity to another FragmentActivity or you have created on activity in which you want to change Fragments inside that activity