# How to call a fragment from a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am making an application.
In this application, I have a fragment that contains a listView. When I click on any item it should start a new fragment which displays the item website. 
My listView fragment code :

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {


private ListView mListViewASSociation;
private ListViewAssociationAdapter mListViewAssociationAdapter;
private ArrayList<ListViewAssociations> mlistviewlist;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;




public MyFragment () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mwl_associations, container, false);
    mListViewASSociation = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.association_list);
    mlistviewlist = new ArrayList<ListViewAssociations>();
    String[] mAssciation_Name ;
    final String Webs[];
    TypedArray Icons ;
    mAssciation_Name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Association_names);
    Webs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Association_websites) ;


    Icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.Association_icons);
    ListViewAssociations MyTitle ;

    for(int i = 0 ; i<mAssciation_Name.length ; i++) {
        MyTitle = new ListViewAssociations(mAssciation_Name[i],Icons.getResourceId(i,R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        mlistviewlist.add(MyTitle);
    }

    mListViewAssociationAdapter = new ListViewAssociationAdapter(getActivity(),mlistviewlist);
    mListViewASSociation.setAdapter(mListViewAssociationAdapter);
```

here I am handling on clicking on an item

```
    mListViewASSociation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            BlankFragment myFragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.fragment_mwl_associations, myFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return rootView ;



}
```

My blankfragment which is called :

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

WebView myWebView;
private String URL  ;
public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

public void setURL(String URL) {
    this.URL = URL;
}

public String getURL() {
    return URL;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_blank);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    myWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(getActivity()), "Android");

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    new LoadViewTask().execute();
    return rootView ;
}
```

when I click on an item my application crashes. Where is the mistake ??

Comment: Can you post the call stack from the logcat?

Comment: what do you mean call stack from a logcat ?the error ???

Comment: there are lots of answer related to this question.. please try to search and try to solve by your own..  before posting question..this might will help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/18375149/3498931

Comment: here is a good picture of a call stack within the log cat http://i.stack.imgur.com/6qdhO.png
call stack is a stack data structure containing a history of method calls that gets printed to the console when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you have done in `onItemClick()` in this line :
change

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.fragment_mwl_associations, myFragment);
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment);
```

Here, you entered the wrong layout id for replace, instead add the `FrameLayout`container id `R.id.container` which you have used to add the `fragment` in your `MainActivity.java`.

reference links would be more helpful:
[Fragments Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: replace should be an ID not a layout.

Comment: yeah..you shoud hav to pass FrameLayout container id there.

Answer (score 0):

Removing "fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);" might help. As mentioned by Scott, the logcat stack (The list of errors) would be helpful.